# Why can't I test for endogeneity by regressing the standard errors on x?

Tags: modeling, econometrics, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, macroeconomics

I have a savings variable that I'm regressing on the real interest rate. I want to test for endogeneity but I don't have any instrumental variable, so I can't use the Hausman test. Why is it not sufficient to just regress the standard errors on the independent variable? Shouldn't that prove whether there is a correlation between them or not?

Comment: you mean to regress the residuals on covariates? your thinking is that since exogenity is defined as independence of errors and covariates, why not regress residuals on covariates. residuals are estimators of errors, not the errors, which you don't observe. that's why

Comment: Please indiicate  your proposed econometric model .